# How to properly get a sprite object in pygame to look at the mouse

Tags: python, pygame

So in this program you are able to move a spaceship around the screen using the WASD keys, and that works fine. But the problem here is that I want the spaceship sprite to rotate based on were the mouse pointer is, basically i want it to look at the mouse. And I kind of got it to work, it wiggles a bit when I move my mouse on the screen, but it doesn't actually rotate. The section were all the angle calculating is, is in the get_angle() and rotate() methods for the spaceship.

my code:

```
import pygame
from livewires import games, color
import math

games.init(screen_width = 700, screen_height = 650, fps = 50)

class Create_spaceship(games.Sprite):
    '''A spaceship controlled by the arrow keys'''        
    def update(self):
        '''Move the coordinates'''
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        dist = 4

        if key[pygame.K_w]:
            self.y -= dist
        if key[pygame.K_s]:
            self.y += dist
        if key[pygame.K_a]:
            self.x -= dist
        if key[pygame.K_d]:
            self.x += dist

        #Check to see if the spaceship is oustside boundries
        if self.left < 0:
            self.left = 0
        if self.right > games.screen.width:
            self.right = games.screen.width
        if self.top < 0:
            self.top = 0
        if self.bottom > games.screen.height:
            self.bottom = games.screen.height

        self.get_angle()

    def get_angle(self):
        '''Will get the angle between the mouse and the image'''
        mouseX = games.mouse.x
        mouseY = games.mouse.y
        spaceshipX = self.x
        spaceshipY = self.y

        self.angle = math.atan2(mouseX - spaceshipX, mouseY - spaceshipY)

        print self.angle
    def rotate(self):
        '''Rotates the sprite at the angle found in get_angle()'''
        self.angle = self.angle


def main():
    screen_background = games.load_image('resized_stars background.png', transparent = False)
    games.screen.background = screen_background

    spaceship_image = games.load_image('8-bit_Spaceship_withBG.png')
    spaceship = Create_spaceship(image=spaceship_image,
                          x = games.mouse.x,
                          y = games.mouse.y)
    games.screen.add(spaceship)
    games.mouse.is_visible = True

    games.screen.mainloop()

main()
```

Comment: I think your question is not about pygame itself, but about livewires.

Answer (score 0):

Use `pygame.transform.rotate(spaceship.angle)`

https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html